# Unable to get apache.exe working as windows service

Tags: windows-server-2008, apache-1.3

I am trying to get `Apache version 1.3.22` to run as a service on `windows 2008 server`.

If i start Apache.exe from the command prompt, it works fine. But when i add i start it as windows service, it throws me an error.

This is how i am adding it as windows service: `sc create Apache binpath= "F:\Program Files\Apache Group\Apache\Apache.exe"`

This is what i see in the event viewer: `Faulting application Apache.exe, version 0.0.0.0, time stamp 0x3bc5ae60, faulting module ApacheCore.dll, version 0.0.0.0, time stamp 0x3bc5ae5e, exception code 0xc0000005, fault offset 0x000251c8, process id 0x1df0, application start time` 0x01d0adf337a5bbaf.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

> Turns out that Windows 2008 has this security feature called "User
>   Account Control" that prevents apache from installing properly as a
>   service.  This can be disabled by clicking on Control Panel-> User
>   Accounts.  Turn it off, reboot, and reinstall apache and everything is
>   fine.
>
> Oh, don't turn UAC back on or Apache will again refuse to start with a
>   1067 error.  I'm sure there is a good reason and a workaround, but I
>   don't think it is worth spending anymore time on.

http://justin.greene.com/2011/11/apache-1341-on-windows-2008.html

So you will need to reinstall with this feature disabled, I would still suggest unless you specifically need 1.3.X install a newer version.

Comment: nope. there is no PHP on the machine. I think it's related to the ConfigArgs parameter in the windows service.

Comment: In the install dir with a command prompt you can run "apache -t" which should test the config

Comment: Also the version you are using is very old "1.3.22: Oct 12, 2001" Is there a reason why you are not using a current release?

Comment: apache-t shows Syntax OK. This is how my ConfigArgs looks like: -d
f:\program files\apache group\apache
-f
f:/Application/Apache/MyApp.httpd.conf
apache -t -f f:/Application/Apache/MyApp.httpd.conf also shows Syntax OK

Comment: I found a blog post talking exactly about what is happening http://justin.greene.com/2011/11/apache-1341-on-windows-2008.html Ill update the initial answer with the solution

Comment: I have other servers that has Apache 2.2 and they work fine so may be i just need to convince users to upgrade the Apache. I can't really disable UAC.

Comment: Well that was about all I could find, that release is 14 years old.